# Tag cleanup required

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Apache 2.4 is sufficiently different from earlier releases that a new tag [apache-2.4](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache-2.4) has recently been created for it. There are a number of questions that have already been asked about Apache 2.4 which have been tagged [apache-2.2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache-2.2), these need to be cleaned up.

If you have some spare time you can use [this query](https://serverfault.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+apache+2.4+-[apache-2.4]+-python) to identify questions that may need a retag and retag them. It's likely that not all of the questions will need retaging but this will get us close.

Comment: sorry for the spamming.  Didn't know it would.  I'll stop now, I think that was around 30 or so questions.

Comment: @TheCleaner If you're going to mass edit, try to do so between 20:00 and 8:00 UTC, when the site is pretty dead anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm declaring this complete. Thanks if you helped.